# Devise Error: NameError (uninitialized constant Unlock)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I recently started getting complaints that locked users cannot reset their accounts from the email I am sending.

I'm getting

> NameError (uninitialized constant Unlock):
>     config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb:6:in `call_with_quiet_assets'

Nothing has changed on my routesr and nothing has changed in my links... what could be causing this error message and how can I fix it?

quiet_assets.rb:

```
Rails.application.assets.logger = Logger.new('log/logger.txt')
Rails::Rack::Logger.class_eval do
  def call_with_quiet_assets(env)
    previous_level = Rails.logger.level
    Rails.logger.level = Logger::ERROR if env['PATH_INFO'].index("/assets/") == 0
    call_without_quiet_assets(env).tap do
      Rails.logger.level = previous_level
    end
  end
  alias_method_chain :call, :quiet_assets
end
```

Stacktrace:

```
INFO  Started GET "/users/unlock?unlock_token=CzpxHwV5kL7EyDZb32Ex" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-22 21:08:56 +0200
INFO  Processing by Devise::UnlocksController#show as HTML
INFO  Parameters: {"unlock_token"=>"CzpxHwV5kL7EyDZb32Ex"}
INFO  -- store_location: /users/unlock?unlock_token=CzpxHwV5kL7EyDZb32Ex
INFO  Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8.1ms
FATAL  NameError (uninitialized constant Unlock):
  config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb:6:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
INFO  Rendered /Users/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.7ms)
INFO  Rendered /Users/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.8ms)
```

Controller

```
require 'white_label_utils'
include ERB::Util
#Need to include these helpers or image_path won't work
include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper

class CustomMailer < Devise::Mailer
  include Devise::Mailers::Helpers
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
  default from: 'no-reply@ourcompany.com'
  # Sends a simple email (without attachments and call to action button)
  # to - array of recipients
  # subject - subject title of email
  # message - body of email
  # section - section used for white labeling purposes
  # file_attachments - array of files attachments to be included in email. eg. [{name: 'myFileName.csv', content: fileData}, {name: 'anotherFileName.zip', content: anotherFileData}] Empty by default
  def simple_email(to, subject, message, section = nil, file_attachments = [])
    get_whitelabel_details(section)
    set_email_global_params(to, subject, message)
    # if there are files, attach them
    file_attachments = [] if file_attachments.nil?
    if file_attachments.length > 0
      file_attachments.each do |file|
        attachments["#{file[:name]}"] = file[:content]
      end
    end
    mail(to: to, subject: @subject, from: @whitelabel.email_from).delivery_method.settings.merge!(Dynamic::Application.config.send_grid_smtp_settings)
  end

  # Sends a devise invitation_instructions email located under app/views/user/mailer/invitation_instructions.html
  def invitation_instructions(record, opts = {})
    to = record.email
    begin
      section = record.publisher.sections.first
    rescue => e
      Rails.logger.warn "Could not find any sections associated with user #{record}"
      section = nil
    end
    initialize_from_record(record)
    get_whitelabel_details(section)
    set_email_global_params(to, invitation_email_subject, I18n.t("devise.mailer.invitation_instructions.message", invitee_name: record.first_name.capitalize, inviter_name: @resource.invited_by.is_dy_admin ? @resource.invited_by.last_name.capitalize : @resource.invited_by.full_name, product_name: @whitelabel.product_name))
    uri = URI.parse(edit_invitations_url({invitation_token: @resource.invitation_token}))
    @cta_text = I18n.t("devise.mailer.invitation_instructions.call_to_action_text")
    @cta_link = whitelabel_links(uri)
    super record, opts
  end

  # Sends a devise unlock_instructions email located under app/views/user/mailer/unlock_instructions.html
  def unlock_instructions(record, opts = {})
    to = record.email
    begin
      section = record.publisher.sections.first
    rescue => e
      Rails.logger.warn "Could not find any sections associated with user #{record}"
      section = nil
    end
    initialize_from_record(record)
    get_whitelabel_details(section)
    set_email_global_params(to, I18n.t("devise.mailer.unlock_instructions.subject"), I18n.t("devise.mailer.unlock_instructions.message"))
    uri = URI.parse(unlock_url(@resource, :unlock_token => @resource.unlock_token))
    @cta_text = I18n.t("devise.mailer.unlock_instructions.call_to_action_text")
    @cta_link = whitelabel_links(uri)
    super record, opts
  end

  # Sends a devise reset_password_instruction email located under app/views/user/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html
  def reset_password_instructions(record, token = nil, opts = {})
    to = record.email
    begin
      section = record.publisher.sections.first
    rescue => e
      Rails.logger.warn "Could not find any sections associated with user #{record}"
      section = nil
    end
    initialize_from_record(record)
    get_whitelabel_details(section)
    set_email_global_params(to, I18n.t("devise.mailer.reset_password_instructions.subject"), I18n.t("devise.mailer.reset_password_instructions.message"))
    uri = URI.parse(edit_password_url(@resource, {reset_password_token: @resource.reset_password_token}))
    @cta_text = I18n.t("devise.mailer.reset_password_instructions.call_to_action_text")
    @cta_link = whitelabel_links(uri)
    super record, opts
  end

  private
  def devise_mail(record, action, opts={})
    initialize_from_record(record)
    (mail headers_for(action, opts)).delivery_method.settings.merge!(Dynamic::Application.config.send_grid_smtp_settings)
  end

  # Customize the subject and sender display name by the white-label profile
  def headers_for(action, opts)
    headers = {:from => @email_from,
               :reply_to => @email_from}
    super.merge!(headers)
  end

  # Overrides the default subject line for devise emails (reset_password_instructions, invitation_instructions, etc)
  def subject_for(key)
    return super unless key.to_s == 'invitation_instructions'
    invitation_email_subject
  end

  # Gets the whitelabel details associated with the section
  def get_whitelabel_details(section)
    @section = section.blank? ? err_message('section') : section
    begin
      @whitelabel = WhiteLabelUtils::get_profile(nil, section.site.publisher)
    rescue => e
      Rails.logger.warn "Could not determine WhiteLabel profile when sending email"
      @whitelabel = WhiteLabelUtils::get_profile(nil, nil)
    end
  end

  # Validates the existence of parameters and assigns them to global vars that will be used in the email template itself
  def set_email_global_params(to, subject, message)
    @errors = nil
    @to = to.blank? ? err_message('to') : to
    @subject = subject.blank? ? err_message('subject') : subject.slice(0, 1).capitalize + subject.slice(1..-1).chomp('.') #remove trailing period, we add this in the template so this avoids duplicates
    @message = message.blank? ? err_message('message') : message.slice(0, 1).capitalize + message.slice(1..-1).chomp('.') #remove trailing period, we add this in the template so this avoids duplicates
    @email_from = @whitelabel.email_from
    @reply_to = @whitelabel.reply_to
    @introduction = create_introduction(to)

    unless @errors.blank?
      raise @errors
    end
  end

  def invitation_email_subject
    I18n.t("devise.mailer.invitation_instructions.subject", product_name: @whitelabel.product_name)
  end

  # Receives a generic url and replaces it with whitelabelled domains
  def whitelabel_links uri
    "#{@whitelabel.root_url_info[:protocol]}://#{@whitelabel.root_url_info[:host]}#{uri.path}?#{uri.query}"
    # rendered as https://companydomain.com/users/unlock?unlock_token=TOKENVALUE
  end

  # Searches the system for a user with 'email_address' and returns
  # a personalized introduction with the user's first name otherwise
  # returns a generic introduction with the wording 'Dear User'
  def create_introduction email_address
    user = User.where(email: email_address).first
    "#{I18n.t("dy.common.general.hi")}#{user.nil? ? '' : " #{user.first_name.capitalize}"},"
  end

  def err_message(val)
    @errors = @errors.blank? ? '<' + val + '> field can not be empty' : @errors + '\n<' + val + '> field can not be empty'
  end

end
```

The route being called is `https://example.com/users/unlock?unlock_token=USERS_TOKEN`
and the controller is from devise unlockscontroller

```
class Devise::UnlocksController < DeviseController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication

  # GET /resource/unlock/new
  def new
    build_resource({})
  end

  # POST /resource/unlock
  def create
    self.resource = resource_class.send_unlock_instructions(resource_params)

    if successfully_sent?(resource)
      respond_with({}, :location => after_sending_unlock_instructions_path_for(resource))
    else
      respond_with(resource)
    end
  end

  # GET /resource/unlock?unlock_token=abcdef
  def show
    self.resource = resource_class.unlock_access_by_token(params[:unlock_token])

    if resource.errors.empty?
      set_flash_message :notice, :unlocked if is_navigational_format?
      respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_unlock_path_for(resource) }
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity){ render :new }
    end
  end

  protected

    # The path used after sending unlock password instructions
    def after_sending_unlock_instructions_path_for(resource)
      new_session_path(resource) if is_navigational_format?
    end

    # The path used after unlocking the resource
    def after_unlock_path_for(resource)
      new_session_path(resource)  if is_navigational_format?
    end

end
```

Comment: Can you show quiet_assets.rb ?

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: Which is line 6?

Comment: Could you post full stack trace?

Comment: @mrzasa added stacktrace

Comment: @CD-RUM line 6 is call_without_quiet_assets(env).tap do

Comment: @AdrianE can you show the controller, please?

Comment: Added controller. Function in question is `def unlock_instructions`
@Neodelf

Comment: @AdrianE there is not a controller - this is a mailer

Comment: The controller is not mine but comes from devise
I have added the URL route and the devise controller in question, but we have not edited this from the default that comes with the gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was never properly resolved. I ended overriding the built-in devise callback functions (which is a horrible practice)

Old versions of Rails3 and Ruby 1.9.3 are most probably the culprits - but I don't have the privilege of upgrading - too much legacy code working in production already.

Story of my life :(